# What could happen if I choose not to use security rules in my Firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-security

I understand that having security is on the top of our "TO-DO" list, we all need it and want it. But i don't understand what could happen if I don't use security rules in my Firebase database.

Currently, I'm developing an app and the way I did it, I haven't implemented security rules to work with the app, so `.read` and `.write` is just set to `true`. User has to log-in through Facebook though to be able to send requests.

I have tried to implement the security rules to work with the app, but I have some bugs, so does it really bother if it stays that way? Is there any way someone could send a "bad" request? What are the risks?

Comment: Downvoters: please leave a comment on why you downvoted. The fact that it is a bad practice to leave a database unsecured, does not make this a bad question. As Mathew shows: it can be answered very clearly, which helps everyone: including people who may stumble upon this question in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With write set to true anybody who finds your app URL could delete your whole database. They could change whatever they want. Android, ios or websites, nothing is safe as they will be able to find the URL easily.

Comment: if the user signs-in and he has auth, and security rules require auth and facebook provider, could it still be done?

Comment: Depends on what your security rules are. If they are just set to true they do not have to sign in.

Comment: If you're saying your write is restricted to them being logged in... then anybody who is logged in could delete your database. At least you're protected from people who are not logged in.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Mathew's answer you'll also want to think about abuse to your database.

Any user who knows the URL of your database can:

- write any data to your database. So by dumping data, they could push your database over its quota and make your app unusable for your actual users.
- use your database for their own uses. They'd be eating up your bandwidth quota. Once your quota has been consumed, your app may become unusable for your actual users.

The above apply to the Spark and Flame plans. If your project is on a metered plan, malicious users can drive up your usage and thus your bill.

Comment: is there any way that someone could get the firebase's url through my app?

Comment: Yes. Since your app needs to know the Firebase URL (and the API key) to access the database, anyone who uses your app has implicit access to these values as well.

Comment: So with security rules you can block the user writing wherever he wants, giving him only access to "his" information, which also that information could have some validation rules, and that is what makes the system secured right?

Answer (score 0):

Your Firebase Rules generally helps you take care of Server side security. and ensures your data are secure and database protected from malicious user.
So Authenticating a user does not in anyway hep protect your database.
So if you dont have rules in place you could lose all your data. An Authenticated user can simply use a sigle line of code " ref.remove() " and viola all you data in your data base is gone so easy.
So please always ensure you write security Rules to make you firebase database secured.